# Circular join (or nested join) between 3 tables

Tags: mysql, join, circular-dependency, nested

I have three tables, `rents[id, contract_id, paid]`, `contracts[id, active, unit_id]` and `units[id]`.
What I need is a query that will select all the rents that are paid AND that their contract is active, and to join the unit to the record.

What I have tried is:

```
SELECT * FROM `rents` AS Rent
LEFT JOIN units AS Unit
    INNER JOIN contracts AS Contract
    ON (Unit.id = Contract.unit_id AND Contract.active=true)
ON Rent.unit_id = Unit.id 
WHERE Rent.paid = true
```

The returned rows were close, I received only the paid rents, with the unit - however, it ignored the contract.active condition.

Can you help please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to be careful with SELECT * here as you have common field names `id` for different fields. It is good practice to only list the actual fields you want:

```
SELECT
  r.id AS `rent_id`,
  c.id AS `contract_id`,
  u.id AS `unit_id`
FROM rents AS r
INNER JOIN contracts AS c
  ON r.contract_id = c.id
INNER JOIN units AS u
  ON c.unit_id = u.id
WHERE r.paid = 'true'
AND c.active = 'true'
```

Also note that I put `true` in single quotes as I am assuming your are using a text string in this field.  You might actually consider using tinyint field and setting value of 1 for true condition, in which case the WHERE clause would look like:

```
WHERE r.paid = 1
AND c.active = 1
```

Note I have used all INNER JOINS as it does not seem you have a case where a rent could exist without a contract and a contract could exists without a unit.  Even if this is possible I don't think it is applicable to your query since you are specifically looking for cases where contracts and units exist.

Comment: @Strawberry Almost what?  Care to elaborate? Ah nevermind. I guess you were talking about this `almost always good practice`.  Well I was being gentle, as I personally would not allow such usage in my codebase for simple selects.

Comment: Thanks! @MikeBrant. 
The LEFT to INNER change is correct, haven't thought about it. just one question: tho your solution works, as I understood, using a 'join' condition has better performance than a 'where' condition?

Comment: @yossi If you have all the fields on which you are joining, filtering, sorting, etc. indexed (as you should), my guess is you are not going to see any sort of performance difference, as when MySQL generates it's query plan it generally determine the best approach for retrieving the data.  To me it is much more readable to not mix the filtering conditions with the join conditions, as from your original example, `Contract.active=true` is not really a join condition but a filter. Of course if this is a large table and you are worried about performance, do some testing.

Answer (score 1):

try moving your logic around a little and getting rid of the LEFT JOIN for another INNER (because without a unit, you can't have a contract)

```
SELECT * 
FROM `rents` AS Rent
INNER JOIN units AS Unit
  ON Rent.unit_id = Unit.id
INNER JOIN contracts AS Contract
 ON Unit.id = Contract.unit_id
WHERE Rent.paid = true
  AND Contract.active=true
```

Comment: Just noted that you had a mistake, i don't have a unit_id col' on rents

Comment: @yossi - mistake? I copied your query. Those are the same joins in your post.

Comment: You are correct! Sorry, seems like i made a mistake there... sorry again
@AgRizzo